# How to disable login / register users in JSPUI 5.6?

Tags: dspace

I need to do a database migration, but I want the repository stay available to users. Disabling just user registration and authentication. I use JSPUI.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable authentication and registration by commenting out the AuthenticationMethod property in dspace/config/modules/authentication.cfg

```
# plugin.sequence.org.dspace.authenticate.AuthenticationMethod = org.dspace.authenticate.PasswordAuthentication
```

To re-enable authentication and registration after you finished the database migration, reinstate the AuthenticationMethod property in dspace/config/modules/authentication.cfg

```
plugin.sequence.org.dspace.authenticate.AuthenticationMethod = org.dspace.authenticate.PasswordAuthentication
```